# Convert an array of an array of an object to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to convert this array of an array of an object to an array. I'd like to just get the email into an array. So this

```
[
  audition {
    dataValues: { email: 'something@something.com' },
    _previousDataValues: { email: 'something@something.com'}
  },
  audition {
    dataValues: { email: 'somethingelse@somethingelse.com' },
    _previousDataValues: { email: 'somethingelse@somethingelse.com'}
  }
]
```

To look like this

```
['something@something.com', 'somethingelse@somethingelse.com']
```

Comment: Your data structure is invalid JS.

Comment: array map.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const arr = [
  {
    dataValues: { email: 'something@something.com' },
    _previousDataValues: { email: 'something@something.com'}
  },
  {
    dataValues: { email: 'somethingelse@somethingelse.com' },
    _previousDataValues: { email: 'somethingelse@somethingelse.com'}
  }
];
const res = arr.map(x => x.dataValues.email);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [
  {
    dataValues: { email: 'something@something.com' },
    _previousDataValues: { email: 'something@something.com'}
  },
  {
    dataValues: { email: 'somethingelse@somethingelse.com' },
    _previousDataValues: { email: 'somethingelse@somethingelse.com'}
  }
];
const finalArray = array.map(entry => {
  return entry.dataValues.email
})
console.log(finalArray);
```

This gives you `["something@something.com", "somethingelse@somethingelse.com"]`